# Display success message after submitting form

Tags: 8, forms

I am try to display an success message after submitting my form and redirect to next page. The code I am using is the following.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Form Submitted Successfully'), 'status', TRUE);
}
```

It doesn't work for me.

Is there any alternate way to do it? What code should I use to display a success message?

Comment: Can you show more code? Did you add the message properly in your submit handler?

Comment: yes   'public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {  drupal_set_message(t('Form Submitted Successfully'), 'status', TRUE);'

Comment: flushed the cache?

Comment: The above code should work.Make sure your form is loading. Clear the cache. Steps given in below link I feel useful.just cross check the steps you followed with this link.Hope it is helpful. http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/step-by-step-method-to-create-a-custom-form-in-drupal-8

Comment: i think you need to clear your cache. the same problem occurred with me once...

Comment: Yeah I clearr the cache its not working

Comment: use   dsm(t('Form Submitted Successfully'), 'status', TRUE);   But that will only work if you have devel module installed. Let me know it worked or not.

Comment: i have devel module but its not working

Comment: once clean urls also...and close your xampp and restart again.... Can u share the the screenshot??.. Like which type of form are you using Flexiform, Entityform  or Webform??? if problem persists...

Comment: drupal web forms

Comment: Did it work??? XAMPP closing and restarting..???

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54552/discussion-between-anirban-neogi-and-karthiga).

Comment: Are you sure that the function is called?

Comment: yes sure I called that method

Answer (score 5):

The code you are showing is the same code Drupal core uses, for example in `BanDelete::submitForm()`.

```php
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $this->ipManager->unbanIp($this->banIp);
  $this->logger('user')->notice('Deleted %ip', [
    '%ip' => $this->banIp,
  ]);
  drupal_set_message($this->t('The IP address %ip was deleted.', [
    '%ip' => $this->banIp,
  ]));
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($this->getCancelUrl());
}
```

As `drupal_set_message()` is used from Drupal core in `submitForm()`, that is expected to work. I cannot say why it doesn't work in your case, since you don't show the full class code. It could also be there is a module that is interfering.

For more OOP code, `drupal_set_message()` has been replaced with a service in Drupal 8.6. The code I showed (which is for Drupal 8.4) has been changed to the following. (See [`BanDelete::submitForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ban%21src%21Form%21BanDelete.php/function/BanDelete%3A%3AsubmitForm/8.9.x).)

```php
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $this->ipManager->unbanIp($this->banIp);
  $this->logger('user')->notice('Deleted %ip', [
    '%ip' => $this->banIp,
  ]);
  $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('The IP address %ip was deleted.', [
    '%ip' => $this->banIp,
  ]));
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($this->getCancelUrl());
}
```

`$this->messenger()` returns an instance of the [messenger](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/messenger/8.9.x) service, the service that replaced `drupal_set_message()` in Drupal 8.